# Pandas installation not recognising a C++ install

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, visual-c++, pip

I'm installing Pandas along with a few others dependencies for a graph theory project on a new machine.

I'm installing all the dependencies with `pip`, with Pandas being installed with `pip install pandas`.

The installation fails with:

```
    running build_ext
    building 'pandas._libs.algos' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptool
s, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q9t
aeyul\\pandas\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" instal
l --record C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9bazi_ha\install-reco
rd.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 i
n C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q9taeyul\pandas\
```

I have then proceeded to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redist 14.0 from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

The C++ 2015 Redist version numbers are 14.0.23026 for 64-bit and 14.0.24215 for 32-bit. I also have various other C++ Redists from other years, down to 2005.

I restarted the computer after installing the Redist, just to ensure there are no problems on that front. However, I'm still getting the same error.
I'm on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

*Visual C++ Redistributable* installs run-time libraries and can be used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ **compiler**! So install [Build Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).